# Behaviour of untranslated fields during translation

Tags: blueprint, localization, translation-manager

it interests me how the fields not marked as translatable behave during translation. For example:

1. I have component in English and its translated to Spanish.
2. I update untranslatable field in English component and send to translation for second time.

**Question:** *Will field be updated after translation in Spanish component (after "re-translation" of already translated component)*

Or case 2:
 1. I have component in English and its translated to Spanish.
 2. I update untranslatable field in Spanish (translated and localized) component and send to translation for second time (from english).

**Question:** *Will field be updated after translation in Spanish component (will it get values from English component)*

Our assumption is that translation works in a way that every time component gets translated, TMS (we use TMS) gets all values from original component, replaces translated fields with translation, and copy all that in "destination" component. Is this indeed the case?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you send component for translation:

- TM get latest version of source component (English)
- Send all fields of source component including non translatable fields to TMS (except for aggregated components it send only translatable fields)
- On retrieve TM apply all fields to target components

So if you change anything in target item it will be overwritten with next translation

Assumption here is that content in target publication should be changed only through translation and users should never change any translatable content on translation target level.

Answer (score 1):

**Question: Will field be updated after translation in Spanish component (after "re-translation" of already translated component)**

My Answer: Spanish (translated and localized) component and you can send to translation for second time from Spanish publication.

**Question: Will field be updated after translation in Spanish component (will it get values from English component)**

Answer: component synchronization best solution for your issue, Please try [component synchronization](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/sdl-content-porters-synchronization-option)